# O que está de errado neste código?

Tags: javascript

```
<span style="margin-left:13%;" id="temporizador">Loading...</span>
<div id="roda"></div>
<div id="ponteiro"><b style="margin-left:15%; margin-top:500px; font-size:16px;">|</b></div>


<script>
setInterval(function(){
$.getJSON("loading.php", function(diego) {
    var loja = diego[0];
    var temporizador = diego[1];

document.getElementById('#temporizador').value = temporizador;

if(temporizador === "00"){

var img = document.querySelector('#roda');


  var graus = Math.random() * 1000;
  img.style.transform = 'rotate(' + graus + 'deg)';

}
});
}, 1000);

</script>
```

Porquê a var temporizador, não está a substituir o valor na div com id temporizador? O que está de errado?

Comment: Sou bem leigo em javascript, mas tenta fazer o seguinte: Ao invés de colocar `document.getElementById('#temporizador')`, tente colocar `document.getElementById('temporizador')`, sem o jogo da velha

Comment: O que dá `console.log(typeof diego, diego);`?